# Есть ли тут что-то наподобие лс?

Tags: поддержка

Можно тут как-то написать участнику сообщение?

Comment: Кроме того, что описано в ответах по ссылке, есть чат. В чате есть довольно много активных участников, можно там попробовать. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и еще можно самому создавать чаты

Comment: @Grundy жалко, что нельзя самому же их и уничтожать.

Comment: @alexolut, по неактивности сами упадут. Возможно, модераторы могут принудительно удалить, если попросить

Comment: @Grundy пассивность это не интересно ... хочется ж бомбануть как следует :-D Кстати, кнопку создания чата я не сразу нашел, пришлось страницу вниз листать. Имхо, это неспроста.

Comment: @alexolut, там еще ограничения есть на создание, и даже на то чтобы писать в чате

Comment: @alexolut не нужно множить сущности (чаты) без необходимости. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin нужен функционал "отметить чат как `дубликат` существующего".

Comment: @alexolut хорошая идея. Кстати, можно сообщения переносить.